# How to get hidden value using Beautiful soup and urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python3 on Windows10X64(Ananconda installed).
I'm trying to get value in "span" element using **urllib** and **BeautifulSoup**,In Chrome, it's show 8000, but it's always give 0 letter for my code result.

Can someone please suggest the way to **get real number as it shown in Chrome web browser** ?

here's my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url ='https://www.futbin.com/18/squad/100133002/sbc'
req = Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page_html = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html,'html.parser')

page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ps4-price"})
```

The result is below.

```
[<div class="ps4-price">
 <img class="price-platform-img" src="https://cdn.futbin.com/design/img/logos/full_small/ps_blue.png"/>
 <div class="price-row-text" id="squad-price-ps3"><span class="psprice2">0</span></div>
 </div>]
```

In the "span" tag, it should show the same value(e.g. 8000,9000) as shown in Chrome/Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div of *ps4-price* is loaded via other request. You could also click on the `REFRESH PRICE` button to have the URL.

https://www.futbin.com/18/getPricesById

The simple solution is via *requests*. You could follow the steps from this website: https://curl.trillworks.com/

### Detailed Steps

1. Open 'https://www.futbin.com/18/squad/100133002/sbc' via Chrome
2. Open Developer Tools - Network tab
3. Click the `REFRESH PRICE` button and you will have this URL under Network tab 'https://www.futbin.com/18/getPricesById'
4. Right click the URL and Copy as cURL
5. Paste on https://curl.trillworks.com/ to get the Python code
6. Since the response is JSON, you can directly extract the price instead of bs4.    `print(response.json()['total_prices']['ps'])`

Comment: Thank you so much, but i'm too newbie with json, may I ask you to put full code or some more explanation ?

Comment: @NNOPP Detailed steps are added as you request.

Comment: Thanks again, I was use your guide to do something much bigger :)

Answer (score 3):

You can in this approach:

```
>>> url = 'https://www.futbin.com/18/squad/100133002/sbc'
>>> req = Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> webpage = urlopen(req).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
>>> required = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"pcdisplay-ps-price"})
>>> x = []
>>> for i in required:
...     x.append(i.get_text())
>>> for i in x:
...     print(i)
...

950
550
750
600
1,300
900
850
550
600
600
600
```

Comment: Thank you, this quite easy for me and now it's works :)

Comment: @NNOPP These prices are not what you mentioned in the question which is range from 8000-9000.

Comment: @northtree You are right, I just tell him that this method is possible to use but need to change tweak a bit, however currently use your method